# Interop directly with office graphing component from c#

Tags: c#, winforms, interop, office-interop

I am working with a legacy application that uses the office graph.exe ( C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\graph.exe )

I add a reference to the graph.exe component in my c# project and when I try to initialize the component I use:

```
using Microsoft.Office;

Interop.Graph.GlobalClass c = new .Interop.Graph.GlobalClass();

Interop.Graph.Application app = c.Application;
```

This does not work and the app seems to reference a null object and can not be used.

Can anyone help me with how to create and initialize the component?

Thanks.

Comment: Works on my machine, although this code cannot compile as posted.  You could only ever get a null object if this code throws an exception.  Force the Platform Target setting if necessary.

Comment: Hey Hans -Thanks!, you got me on track. Believe it or not when I change my culture to us-en things work fine, but if I use my current culture (icelandic) everything blows up.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that interoping with microsoft office graph.exe (f.e. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\graph.exe) does not work on certain international cultures, it works for example for the "en-us" culture but not for the "is-is" culture.